# UIScrollView with keyboard visible

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` (which is also a `UIScrollView`) which contains a bunch of text. In the screenshot there is more text *underneath* the keyboard. I can't scroll up to see that text - no matter what I do that text remains underneath the keyboard.

How can I fix things so that I can scroll to see *all* the text?

[image]

Comment: You should listen for keyboard notifications and modify content inset (or scrollview frame) when neccessary. In your case the scrollview "doesn't know" that part of it is covered by keyboard. [This project](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) should get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works and it's pretty simple.

In .h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *tv;
@property CGSize keyboardSize;
```

In .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Register for keyboard notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void) keyboardWillShow: (NSNotification*) aNotification {

// Get the keyboard size from the notification userInfo
NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
self.keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

// Adjust the content inset from the bottom by the keyboard's height
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, self.keyboardSize.height, 0);
self.tv.contentInset = contentInsets;
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide: (NSNotification*) aNotification {

// Reset the content inset when the keyboard is dismissed
self.tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this solution it worked for me, it is better to change insets rather than content size

Answer (score 1):

The `scrollView` has a property called `contentSize` which determines the area up to which the user can scroll. You would have to manually change this value to compensate the extra scroll space due to the keyboard.

What I suggest is to register for the notifications `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`.

When the keyboard is about to show, the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification is fired and in the corresponding method add the keyboard height to the scroll `contentSize` height.

Similarly, deduct this height fom the scroll `contentSize` height in the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` notification.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid all the manual resizing and stuff, I recommend using this great library  - https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager. It will do all the hard work for you.